# fullStory react native exclude from metro server

Tags: react-native

I see on the fullstory website

```
The FullStory React Native Plugin does not currently work with the Metro Server or with Non-Ejected Expo apps.

Ejected Expo apps are fully supported. If you want to use the Metro Server for local development, we recommend disabling FullStory for these builds.
```

Right now my app build on android fails on how do i disable fullStory in local development?